# WCF отсутствует атрибут ServiceBehavior

Tags: c#, wcf

Хочу создать простой чат для курсовой на MAUI с использованием WCF. Столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия атрибута ServiceBehavior. Сейчас в проекте только 2 wcf файла interface IService и сам класс.
Подскажите как можно её исправить? Может в файле конфигурации что то не то?

[image: отсутствие вообще всх атрибутов кроме этих 2х]

**Файл конфигурации:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="FlamChat">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service name="FlamChat.FlamChatService" behaviorConfiguration="FlamChat">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FlamChat.IFlamChatService">
              <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/FlamChat/FlamChatService/" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: WCF убран из .NET так, как ему на замену пришли такие вещи, как gRPC. Сам WCF переехал в [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF), и то, не до конца. Так что, смотрите внимательней, что и как вы там используете, если у вас .NET Framework (что зря), классы быть должны, если .NET, то нужен дополнительный NuGet пакет, либо вовсе отказ от WCF.